# How to invoke a method in an external function

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I need a `reservation` function that calls the appropriate methods of the class.

But how can I pass the argument to the method if I have to provide user input outside the class?

```
class Stay:
    def __init__(self):
        self._type_room= ''

    def set_type_room (self, NewRoom):

        NewRoom= select_room()
        self._type_room= NewRoom


def select_room():  
    Newroom= input ('insert')
    if NewRoom == 'Single':
        print ('ok')
    else:
        print ('only Single')
    return NewRoom

def reservation ():
    stay= Stay()
    stay.set_type_room(NewRoom)
```

Comment: Not sure what is being asked here. Can you clarify what the code isn't doing that it is supposed to?

Comment: If I start the code tells me that "NewRoom" is not defined.

Comment: You should remove `NewRoom` from the last line and from the `set_type_room` method's arguments.

Comment: Why would you pass in a parameter then immediately replace it with the return value from `select_room`? That clearly makes no sense.

Comment: I have given as an argument "NewRoom" to "set_type_room" because the "setMethod" require necessarily an argument, or not?

Comment: how can I fix my code so that makes sense ?

Comment: It doesn't require an arguments because you are getting a variable from `select_room`, which returns it to `NewRoom` inside the `set_type_room`. What you should do is remove the `NewRoom` argument from `set_type_room` and don't pass it on the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NewRoom` is not defined (does not exist) inside the function `reservation` or in the global scope, so you cannot access it.

You are needlessly passing an argument to `set_type_room`, when you are re-creating it through `select_room` function.

So, you can just remove that parameter and you should be fine:

```
class Stay:
    def __init__(self):
        self._type_room= ''

    def set_type_room (self):
        self._type_room = select_room()


def select_room():  
    Newroom= input ('insert')
    if NewRoom == 'Single':
        print ('ok')
    else:
        print ('only Single')
    return NewRoom

def reservation ():
    stay= Stay()
    stay.set_type_room()
```

If you want the `set_type_room` to be setter method:

```
class Stay:
    def __init__(self):
        self._type_room= ''

    def set_type_room (self, NewRoom):
        self._type_room = NewRoom

def select_room(stay):  
    NewRoom = input ('insert')
    if NewRoom == 'Single':
        print ('ok')
    else:
        print ('only Single')
    stay.set_type_room(NewRoom)

def reservation ():
    stay = Stay()
    select_room(stay)
```

Comment: Also the assignment to `NewRoom` could be trivially factored out.

Comment: Good point. I will update the answer

Comment: it is correct to use these external functions ? I must necessarily use a class in this project

Comment: You can add those functions to class as methods if you want to. You just need to indent them and add `self` as first parameter. Then invoke them with `stay.method(...)` instead of just `method(...)`

Comment: Ok, thanks you! I was using the " NewRoom " parameter because my professor said that in a " setMethod " you need to pass a parameter over self ... other recommendations ?

Comment: Oh, then you need to change the set_type_room to behave like a setter, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: so it is good, but I need a " setter method" and the user input must stay out of the class , by the project required ... :(

Comment: Oh, ok then, I will update again

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes thanks. In this way , however, it has the sense to use the class ? or it was avoidable at this point

Comment: You can always create a program in many, many different ways. You could have created a straight-line program, without functions or classes as well, if you wanted to. But, having classes and functions makes code easier to read, modify, reuse, debug, etc.